# Expression to pass value of an attribute of a selected feature to field in another layer

Tags: qgis, expression

I have two tables: "enforcements_live" and "enforcement". I'm trying to pass the value of an attribute for the selected feature in the `enforcements_live` layer (value from field `fref`) through to the `enforcement` layer (field `enfref`) but only when a feature is selected in `enforcements_live`.

e.g. I want the value of the `fref` field for the selected feature in table `enforcements_live` to be passed through to the field `enfref` of table `enforcement` at the time I create my new feature in table `enforcement`.

I've attempted this through the `is_selected` and `get_feature` functions but I'm only getting a null value being returned. Is this something that's possible to do? From searching, I haven't been able to find any working examples.

Comment: Given that you have tried get_feature, is a workaround accepted based on the value of another defining field, and not the selection of the enforcements_live table?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the value of 'fref' for the selected feature within enforcement_live to be passed through to enfref in the enforcement table. It may be my poor implementation of the functions as I'm quite new to this. I'm trying to use this expression for a default value in the attribute form.

Comment: What I meant was, instead of passing the value by selection, what if you passed it based on the value of another field? To add a new field 'define' on enforcement_live and based on the value of that field to pass the value of field 'fref'. If that's acceptable, I can post an answer based on that.

Comment: Please, post the expression that you have tried.

Comment: @kowalski I see what you mean now, unfortunately passing the value by selection is the only viable method I can think of. The purpose behind this which I haven't already mentioned is to build a workspace for a specific user group, I'm trying to remove as much manual work for them as possible and having the ability to select a feature on one layer and pass that features attributes when creating a new feature on a different layer would be very useful, however, if I can't make it work then manually typing a value will have to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand, you need an expression that returns the value of the **fref** field of the selected feature of the **enforcements_live** table. You will need to [`aggregate`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate) filtering by the function [`is_selected`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#is-selected). Use this expression.

```
aggregate(
    layer:='enforcements_live', -- set here your layer name/id
    aggregate:='array_agg',
    expression:="fref", -- set the field
    filter:=is_selected(
        'enforcements_live',
        $currentfeature
    )
)[0]
```

*Note: if there are more than one features selected it will take randomly the value of just one.*